# jQuery simple show/hide large image from thumbnail click

Tags: jquery

I've got the latest version of jquery library installed and just want a simple lightbox effect (preferably without having to install any additional libraries).

When a thumbnail image from my carousel widget (jcarousel lite) is clicked, I want to show a full size image of that same image in a closable window and grey out the background.

I'd also like to apply this same behavior to a simple thumbnail that's not part of the carousel widget.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm trying to understand what the question is? Do you have code you've tried doing this with that isn't working?

Comment: Why do you qualify this with "preferably without having to install any additional libraries"? jQuery without using additional plugins makes no sense when you can easily find any number of plugins that can do what you are looking for. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @charles - I just want to make sure I'm fully utilizing what I already have, vs adding more code to my app for such a tiny little function as displaying an image over the app with a close box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Like [jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html). Granted, it's another library, but well worth it! I include this library in MOST of my web projects.

Just pop this line into your HEAD tag, and it also includes the jQuery Lib.

```
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.3/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
```

Once that's done, just use the [Overlay](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/index.html) library. I use this to pop-up images, forms, or anything else.

Essentially, you just **create a div**:

```
<div id="image1" class="modalBox">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    content
</div>
```

**Style it:**

```
.modalBox {
    background-color:#fff;
    display:none;
    width:350px;
    padding:15px;
    text-align:left;
    border:2px solid #600;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 50px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 50px #ccc;
    position:fixed;
    _position:absolute;
}
.modalBox h2 {
    background:url(images/logoac.png) no-repeat;
    margin:0px;
    padding:10px 0 10px 110px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #333;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#600;
    font-family:calibri, hevetica, tahoma, arial;
    text-align:right;
}
```

**Create a JS function to popup divs**

```
var api;
function showDiv(v){
    if (api)  //close any pop-ups that might already be open
        if (api.isOpened)
            api.close();

    if (!document.getElementById(v)) return;

    api=$('#'+v).overlay({
        mask: {color: '#000000'},   
        top:'0px',
        api: true           
    }).load();
}
```

**Then When you click a "link" just call:**

```
showDiv('image1'); //change image1 to the name of the div with your content
```

There are even a handful of nice animations and effect to go along with the library (like the [Apple Effect](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/apple.html) and the [Drop Effect](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/custom-effect.html)

Highly customizable and highly useful!

Comment: Thanks for the well thought out response :)

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the jqueryui dialogs:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/